Why does my PMSM motor stop unexpectedly?

I have two PMSM motors, motor1 with 8 pole pairs and motor2 with 17 pole pairs
I use a gyroscope to measure speed;
I use PID controller1 and PID controller2 set two velocity for motor1 and motor2;
I do not use PID controller for current;
motor1 and motor2 run at a low speed;
I blocked the motor1 with my hand, and it stopped. I let go and it started running again.
I blocked the motor2 with my hand and the motor lost torque and stop it(like the electrical angle is wrong)
I swapped the motor connections, motor1 is ok, motor2 is not ok;

Is this because my motor is broken or is it due to some other reason?

I transferred the code executed by the motor from the main function to the interrupt function of current acquisition. When the motor is running, if you stop it with your hand, you will feel the step, and the specific position of each step will stop the motor.


Does motor 2 start when powered up?

@JohnBirckhead Motor 2 starts up with the current. If the current is slightly higher, it will not start up. Motor 1 starts up normally.

@Velvet Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

@admanaglee - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "áccepting" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either your answer or another answer, if one is written & if you consider it the best one. TY

I found my fault. the motor resistance only 0.91 ohm, but need 12v voltage; My program hasn't current loop. if the motor run the current is too high, motor driver hardware protect itself. And motor lost the torque.
